# How to prove that $ \mbox{im}(B) = \mbox{im}(BA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times m} $ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Further assume that $\mbox{im}(A) = \mathbb{R}^m$:
> Show that this implies $ \mbox{im}(B) = \mbox{im}(BA)$.

I am not quite sure how to show it.

I have to show
$$ \mbox{im}(A) \subset \mbox{im}(BA)$$

Therefore, let $ y \in \mbox{im}(B), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then you have $BAx=y$ because $Ax \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mbox{im}(A)= \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now we have to show that $$ \mbox{im}(BA) \subset \mbox{im}(A)$$

$$\mbox{im}(BA) = \{ BAx: x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$
Then I could say again that $Ax \in \mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mbox{im}(A)= \mathbb{R}^m$. That means $Ax$ can be any vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$. That means again:

$$\mbox{im}(BA) = \{ BAx: x\in \mathbb{R}^n\} = \{ By: y \in \mathbb{R}^m \} = \mbox{im}(B)$$

I am not quite sure if that is a rigorous way of proving the statement, so I wanted to ask you whether you could provide a proof in a rigorous way.
Thank you!

Comment: Is ran the range? Latex has $\text{im} (A)$.

Comment: Oh, I will change it!

Comment: How would it look like if I wanted to write it with Latex? I mean the command?

Comment: It could be \text{im} or \operatorname{im}, which is better.

Comment: Someone is changing my text in a wrong why it is not lesser than it should mean subset

Comment: Thanks, I edited my text again.

Comment: $\subset$ or $\subseteq$?

Comment: I don't know really... To prove sets you have to show that one set is the subset of the other and vice versa

Comment: You are referring to $A = B \iff A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  You could forget the matrices completely, and just use functions.  Prove: If $A : U \to V$ and $B : V \to W$ and $A$ is *onto*, then $\operatorname{im}(B) = \operatorname{im}(B\circ A)$.

Comment: How would be the approach if we do not forget the matrices completely? So the approach I tried to prove the statement? If you can answer me that, you will directly get the mark on your answer! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You are talking about $\operatorname{im} A$ in there, which is irrelevant for your problem.  You need to discuss $\operatorname{im} B$ and $\operatorname{im} (BA)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest pushing this through in terms of dimension of the image, i.e. the rank. In general you have
$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}
\rank(BA) \leq \rank(B)$
which holds because
$\renewcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\im(BA) \subseteq \im(B)$,
and equality is met *iff* $\im(B) \subseteq \im(BA)$.

The result is almost immediate: use the surjectivity of $A$ and select $X$ such that $AX = I_m$.

$$\rank(B) = \rank(BI_m) = \rank(BAX) \leq \rank(BA) \leq \rank(B)$$
$$\implies \rank(B) = \rank(BA)\implies \im(B) = \im(BA)$$